# glm math library rotate around target

Tags: c++, opengl, linear-algebra, glm-math

I'm trying to use the GLM Math library in C++ to create a 'satelite' orbiting Earth and always pointing at the center of the Earth. Let's assume this satelite is always 10,000 units away from Earth.

I think the equivalent operation I need is something like a lookRotation to perform a spherical linear interpoloation(SLERP) but I cannot quite figure it out.

I sort of understand that I need the cameras up, forward, and right vectors, and to have those point towards the Earth. I then sort of understand that I need to perform a rotation of my satelite from the Earth's center, and then translate my satelite away 10,000 units.

How can I do so using GLM (with quaternions or euler angles)?

Comment: For satellite orbiting the Earth you don't need things like quarterions or euler angles. Just `glm::rotate()` to rotate the satellite each frame by a given angle - and `glm::translate()` to move it right away from the Earth exactly like you figured it out yourself. It will be always pointing towards the Earth accordingly (if you set it "backward" at the center). This is the simplest 3D animation possible.

Comment: Hmm, I understand how to do the rotation (e.g. a moon rotating around the Earth), but how do I keep the satelite facing the Earth? the satelite orbits won't it also have to turn towards the center? This is a continuous rotation

Comment: Even if the "moon" was cube-shaped it would still face the Earth with the same wall because we do the rotation first while in the center (so the moon gets rotated) and only then we do a translation sending it away (in a different angle - hence direction, but with the same orientation towards the Earth).

Comment: I see, that makes sense! Now if i was placing a 'camera' as a satelite, would I be able to follow the same pattern? Perhaps I would have to inverse the operations?

Comment: For camera position there is `glm::lookAt()` function. Perhaps you can perform above transformations first and then call `glm::lookAt()` - on the top of the matrix stack to get the camera move around. But I haven't tested this like that. Good luck!